# Python data structure and their C++ equivalent

Tags: python, c++

I am looking for python equivalent to these data structure in C++

```
map<string,set<string>>
```

1. sorted by key
2. the value to be a set

and

```
map<key,val>
```

1. sorted by key

After reading this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict
I still didn't find anything suitable.

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you mean by "sorted by key".

Comment: I used defaultdict for the dictionary of sets: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects 
the extracing in Olog(n) *easily* remained a puzzle for me. 
The solution I have now: sort the dictionary, do a binary search yourself...

Answer (score 0):

In python do you have 4 data structures: lists, tuples, sets and dicts.
You can create your own structure combining them:

First:

```
data = {'my_set':set()}
```

Second:

```
data = {'key': 'value'}
```

And you can sort this data structures using the collections module.
[How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: "And you can sort this data structures using the collections module." What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: This structures are not ordered by default, are hashable data structures, if you want that the information to be ordered you will need to use OrderedDict like Masque said in the another answer.

Comment: like @timgeb said ordereddict orders by the order we inserted the elements....
The point for me of having a sorted dictionary is that I could search in Olog(n) If I sort the data structure each time it only hurts my performance.

Answer (score -1):

There is no perfect mapping between c++ and python; python is dynamically typed.

`map<string,set<string>>` is equivalent to (using `OrderedDict` to preserve the order of the keys, otherwise, `dict` suffice.): 
`OrderedDict()`, where the `keys` are strings, and the `values` are `sets` in which you insert strings

```
from collections import OrderedDict  
a = OrderedDict()

a['my_key'] = set()
a['my_key'].add('my_string')
```

> note. The OrderedDict will not be ordered "by key", but by insertion
>   order of the keys (thanks to @timgeb in the comments)

Comment: That would have been my answer, too. Just a note. The `OrderedDict` will not be ordered "by key", but by insertion order of the keys.

Comment: like @timgeb said ordereddict orders by the order we inserted the elements....
The point for me of having a sorted dictionary is that I could search in Olog(n)

Comment: You can sort the dictionary keys, using the ordering you like, before accessing the values.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque but when pulling an element out of the dictionary:
example: a['my_key'] 
how it would know it is sorted and to use binary search?

Comment: You can extract the values in a sequence following an ordering of the keys`[(k, data[k]) for k in sorted(data.keys())]`

Comment: @NoaYehezkel The answer is that `OrderedDict` is not equivalent to `std::map` regarding element order. AFAIK, there is no equivalent in the python standard library.